# display select collect hash ActiveRecord - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Could you help me to display the data of a HASH in a select of my view. I have my hash data in the view but I need the option value to have the IDs.

Rails 5.2.2

```
<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Select</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
        <%= f.select(:prevision, Usuario::PREVISION.collect{ |u| [u]}, {prompt: 'Seleccionar tipo de previsión'}, {:class=>'form-control m-b',readonly: true ,required: true}) %>
   </div>
</div>
```

view inspected code

```
<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Select</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control m-b" readonly="readonly" required="required" name="paciente[prevision]" id="paciente_prevision"><option value="">Seleccionar tipo de previsión</option>
             <option value="FONASA">FONASA</option>
             <option value="ISAPRE">ISAPRE</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

MODEL

```
class Usuario < ApplicationRecord


 FONASA  = 1
 ISAPRE  = 2

 PREVISION = [
   :FONASA,
   :ISAPRE
 ]

end
```

Comment: Your data is not a `Hash` it is an Array and 2 Integers all 3 of which are referenced by constants. Your data would be much easier to use if it was a Hash though e.g. `PREVISION = {FONASA: 1, ISAPRE: 2}`. Then you could use it as `Usuario::PREVISION.to_a` in your `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fetch them in your controller like so

```
@prevision = Usuario::PREVISION
```

Then you can add them in your `.erb` file like so:

```
<select class="form-control m-b" readonly="readonly" required="required" name="paciente[prevision]" id="paciente_prevision"><option value="">Seleccionar tipo de previsión</option>
  <% @prevision.each do |p| %>   
    <option value="<%= p %>"><%= p %></option>    
  <% end %>
</select>
```

To add on based on @engineersmnky's comment, if you want it to be a hash then you need to make your model have:

```
PREVISION = {
  '1': 'FONASA',
  '2': 'ISAPRE',
}
```

Then you need to change your views code to:

```
<select class="form-control m-b" readonly="readonly" required="required" name="paciente[prevision]" id="paciente_prevision"><option value="">Seleccionar tipo de previsión</option>
  <% @prevision.each do |key, value| %>   
    <option value="<%= key %>"><%= value %></option>    
  <% end %>
</select>
```